# How to give a * (asterisk) near to the price of each product?

Tags: product

I need to give a * (asterisk) near the price for each product. As per in the image it will be show like as indicated in the red color.

[image]

Comment: there are two options..one by directly changing price.phtml file and other by jquery...

Comment: please upvote so it could help others.. thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this by changing the `price.phtml` at a lot of spaces to get the `*` inside of the `<span>` elements.